# Puppet Apache Expires Code

Tags: apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

We moving to using Puppet to manage.  Using the apache module (from Puppet).

Trying to figure out syntax to make puppet produce something like:

```
<Directory "/data/websites/mysite">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 12 hours"
   ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 12 hours"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 12 hours"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 12 hours"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 12 hours"
   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 12 hours"
</Directory>
```

I tried this:

```
  apache::vhost {  'mysite':
    servername      => 'mysite.com',
    vhost_name      => $::ipaddress,
    port            => '80',
    docroot         => $docroot,

    directories => [
      {
        path => '/var/www/mysite,
        provider => 'directory',
        options => ['-Indexes','FollowSymLinks'],
        expires_active  => 'On',
        expires_default => 'access plus 0 seconds',
        expires_by_type => [
          {'text/javascript' => 'access plus 12 hours' },
          {'application/x-javascript' => 'access plus 12 hours' },
          {'text/css' => 'access plus 12 hours' },
          {'image/gif' => 'access plus 12 hours' },
          {'image/jpeg' => 'access plus 12 hours' },
          {'application/x-shockwave-flash' => 'access plus 12 hours' },
        ],
      },
    ],

  }
```

This will create this which is not quite what I want:

```
  <Directory "/var/www/mysite">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault access plus 0 seconds
    ExpiresByType {"text/javascript"=>"access plus 12 hours"}
    ExpiresByType {"application/x-javascript"=>"access plus 12 hours"}
    ExpiresByType {"text/css"=>"access plus 12 hours"}
    ExpiresByType {"image/gif"=>"access plus 12 hours"}
    ExpiresByType {"image/jpeg"=>"access plus 12 hours"}
    ExpiresByType {"application/x-shockwave-flash"=>"access plus 12 hours"}
  </Directory>
```

The ExpiresDefault and ExpiresByType is not working.  The rest looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to:

```
  apache::vhost {  'mysite':
    servername      => 'mysite.com',
    vhost_name      => '1.1.1.1',
    port            => '80',
    docroot         => 'mydocroot',
    directories => [
      {
        path => '/var/www/mysite',
        provider => 'directory',
        options => ['-Indexes','FollowSymLinks'],
        expires_active  => 'On',
        expires_default => '"access plus 0 seconds"',
        expires_by_type => [
          'text/javascript "access plus 12 hours"',
          'application/x-javascript "access plus 12 hours"',
          'text/css "access plus 12 hours"',
          'image/gif "access plus 12 hours"',
          'image/jpeg "access plus 12 hours"',
          'application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 12 hours"',
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

You get:

```
  <Directory "/var/www/mysite">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 12 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 12 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 12 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 12 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 12 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 12 hours"
  </Directory>
```

I didn't dig deep enough to decide whether this behaviour is as-documented, is confusing and should be fixed, should be better documented, or is unexpected.

If it is anything other than as-documented, then definitely someone should raise a pull request to improve the Apache module.

Comment: I think you don't want to add 'ExpiresByType' to every lines, your output will not work with 'ExpiresByType ExpiresByType'

Comment: Good pickup, fixed.

Comment: This is definitely expected behavior given how the String type works in Puppet and is also seems to be the best answer possible for this question.

Comment: I do think having to specify `'"access plus 0 seconds"'` i.e. the quoting there is a bit confusing.